# I can't figure out what is wrong with this threads, I am trying to understand multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

I am sorry that this is too long, and it may seem as too much asking, but If you can figure out what is wrong at a glance, please let me know.

In this program I try to input some words (phrase) from the keyboard every time taking one token and assign it to an object `sharedStorer` (then print the assigned value to keep track of what is input as I have a chain of words to input separately). This is done by one thread (Thread of class `Retriever` which `implements` `Runnable`)

There is another thread of `class TokenReader` that reads the value of `sharedStorer` and print it out. `TokenReader` waits for `Retriever` for input and when `Retriever` tries to input while `TokenReader` has not yet read the previous token `Retriever` waits.

The question I have is that at the end `TokenReader` waits forever for `Retriever` which has completed its task, and so the program never terminates.

Here is all 4 classes (and 1 Interface) I am using to perform the desired task.

```
package Multithreads;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class ExerciseTest {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    ExecutorService app=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    Storer st=new SyncStorer();

    System.out.println("Operation performed\t\t Value");
    try{
    app.execute(new Retriever(st));
    app.execute(new TokenReader(st));
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    app.shutdown();
}

}
```

---

```
package Multithreads;

public interface Storer {

public void set(String token);
public String get();
}
```

---

```
package Multithreads;

import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Retriever implements Runnable {

private Scanner scanner;
private String token;
private String currentToken;
private Storer sharedStorer;
private Random rd=new Random();
public int tokenLength=0;

public Retriever(Storer st) {

    sharedStorer=st;

}
public Retriever() {

}
@Override
public void run() {

    System.out.println("Enter a phrase");
    scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    token=scanner.nextLine();
    StringTokenizer tokenizer=new StringTokenizer(token);

    while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        tokenLength++;
        currentToken=tokenizer.nextToken();
        try{

        Thread.sleep(10*rd.nextInt(2000));
        sharedStorer.set(currentToken);

        }catch(NoSuchElementException e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Done Inputting The phrase");

}

}
```

---

```
package Multithreads;

import java.util.Random;

public class TokenReader implements Runnable {

private Random rd=new Random();

private Storer sharedStorer;
Retriever rtr=new Retriever();
private int count=rtr.tokenLength;

public TokenReader(Storer st) {
    sharedStorer=st;
}

@Override
public void run() {
String str="null";
    int i=0;
    try {
        while(i &lt;= count){
        Thread.sleep(15*rd.nextInt(2000));
        str=sharedStorer.get();

        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Consumer done reading");
}


}
```

---

```
package Multithreads;

import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class SyncStorer implements Storer {

private Lock accessLock=new ReentrantLock();

private Condition canInput = accessLock.newCondition();
private Condition canRead = accessLock.newCondition();

private String string="null";
private boolean isEmpty=false;

@Override
public void set(String token) {
    accessLock.lock();
    try
    {
        while(isEmpty){
            System.out.println("Retriever waiting");
            canInput.await();
        }
        string=token;
        isEmpty=true;
        System.out.println("Retriever inputs\t\t "+string);

        canRead.signal();
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        accessLock.unlock();
    }

}

@Override
public String get() {

    accessLock.lock();
    try{
        while(!isEmpty)
        {               
            System.out.println("No token to read");
            canRead.await();
        }
        isEmpty=false;
        System.out.println("TokenReader reads\t\t "+string);


        canInput.signal();
    }catch(InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        accessLock.unlock();
    }
    return string;
}

}
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem that is causing the app to run forever is that this is an infinite loop:

```
    while(i <= count){
        Thread.sleep(15*rd.nextInt(2000));
        str=sharedStorer.get();

    }
```

because you are not decrementing `i`.  And the interrupt-based mechanism you are trying to use to break out of the loop (via an exception!) is broken too.

The `Thread.sleep(15*rd.nextInt(2000))` line looks like a hack so that you can get an `InterruptedException` when the task is interrupted, but:

- the point of sleeping for a *random* number of milliseconds escapes me, and
- it would be simpler to just call `Thread.interrupted()`.

Besides, the *approach* isn't reliable anyway because there is a chance that the interrupt will happen *after* the point at which you are waiting / testing for it; i.e. in the `get()` call.  And if that `get()` call is never going to return because the `store` is empty and the retriever has ended ... then you will wait "for ever".

There is one final problem.  You need to call `app.shutdownNow()` if you want the executor service to interrupt the worker threads ...

---

If I was trying to implement this (using interrupts), I'd change it so that `get` and `set` didn't "gobble up" the interrupt.  If they see the interrupt, they should either:

- allow the `InterruptedException` to propagate (after relevant cleanup), or
- set the thread's interrupted flag again in the exception handler.

Comment: I'm sorry for being late, I changed and incremented i as you noticed  to cause an infinite loop,and later used the approach of Consumer/Producer with ArrayblockingQueue as I found it later in the book I am using, It really shrunk the lines in SyncStorer class but the problem was not there as I realized it later. On what concern getting the Thread to sleep for a random number of milliseconds it helps to ignore exactly when threads are executing. nwy I couldn't get well most about of your answer and as a beginner I don't want to get stuck in advanced stuff I plan to come back later on it.thanks